# carriage characters are lost in the resulted string when reading a file on windows

Tags: python, windows, io

When reading a txt file in windows by python, carriage characoters are lost in resulted string.

c:/text.txt

```
aaa\r\nbbb\r\nccc\r\nddd
```

code:

```
input = open('c:/text.txt')
str = input.read()
import repr
for i,ch in enumerate(str):
    print i,ord(ch),repr.repr(ch)
```

result:

```
0 97 'a'
1 97 'a'
2 97 'a'
3 10 '\n'
4 98 'b'
5 98 'b'
6 98 'b'
7 10 '\n'
8 99 'c'
9 99 'c'
10 99 'c'
11 10 '\n'
12 100 'd'
13 100 'd'
14 100 'd'
```

you can see that all carriage characters are lost.
Any suggestion appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open the file in text mode, Windows line endings `\r\n` are automatically substituted by standard line endings `\n`.  To prevent this from happening, open the file in binary mode:

```
input = open('c:/text.txt', 'rb')
```

Comment: -1 No, he's wrong. Python 2.7 says `ValueError: mode string must begin with one of 'r', 'w', 'a' or 'U', not 'b'`

Comment: @John: Thanks for pointing this out.  I really have to be more careful!

Comment: @Jonn: Thank you. I almost ignored that.